# Mutual friends of two users who are not friends on facebook using Parse and Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using the latest Parse SDK 1.7.1 and Facebook SDK 4.0.1 on my iOS application. My users can only log in using their facebook account.

A very important feature I need, is showing the number of facebook friends `user1` has in common with another `user2` (who is probably not friends with `user1` on facebook). Let us assume for the following that I do get the `user_friends` permission from both users.

My first question concerns the following quote from the [Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user.context/mutual_friends):

> Additionally, the response will only include any mutual friends who
>   have granted user_friends to the app.

Does this mean that `user1` will only see mutual friends that **also use my app**? Is it possible to just retrieve the **number** of mutual friends, without the actual list of friends?

My next question concerns the following statement in the [Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user.context/mutual_friends):

> If you want to call this endpoint on behalf two app-users who are not
>   friends, then you must provide the appsecret_proof parameter along
>   with the user access token when making the request. This means you
>   must call this endpoint from your server.

How does this work together with Parse? Would I need to do this in Cloud-Code? If so, does anyone happen to have some example code for me of how to do a Graph API request from Cloud-Code? I am not familiar with Cloud-Code yet.

Thank you very much in advance for your help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: got solution for this, i am trying to do the same ?